# Best method for GPU to CPU communication in OpenCL

Tags: c, opencl, gpu, gpgpu

I have a kernel that takes no input and whose work items don't communicate with each other. Each work item operates on a different argument based on its `global_id`, but this is not passed in. I want each work item to process its task, screen the result based on some criteria, and write back the result into a global memory array if it meets this criteria. What is the best way to do this? I considered a `__global` index that would start at `0` and increment on each write, but there is no lock on this access and the parallel processes end up in a bunch of race conditions, so I don't know where to tell each work item to write to in the output array.

If this were a higher level language, I would expect to be able to pass in a shared hash or something and just push the successful outputs onto it, key'd by `global_id`, but I'm having trouble figuring out what the most appropriate way to do this is in OpenCL land. Any thoughts? I am using vanilla C, not C++.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/atom_inc.html) looks like exactly what I needed, I just lacked the googlefu to get to it!

Please respond if you have any other suggestions on best practices, but for future reference, the above coupled with a `__global` memory buffer will fulfill my needs.

Comment: Atomics can indeed solve this, but will be slow if the results are not sparse (i.e., if most work items access the atomic, there will be lots of serialization). If many or most work items return results, just make it so every work item results a result (some can be null or empty) and then the CPU can take a pass over the results and pull out the valid data. Or run a *reduction* on the GPU if that would be worth it (performance-wise).

Comment: thanks! for my use case, only 8-10 work items would need to access the atomic global, out of ~10 million, so it's perfect for that. I will look into reductions though, that sounds like a thread I'd like to pull on for another project...